# Can't seem to get the 2nd option to work

Tags: python

I have this following snippet of code which will when I connect to work, I can run this one script and it will load everything I need.  Apologies if I have missed something obvious I was working on their last night while doing a power down at work :-)

It will work on the first argument and connect to the site, but then if I run it again it won't disconnect it tells me I am already connected.

Thanks in advance

```
import subprocess    
import sys      
import os

if 'c' or 'C' in sys.argv[1]:
  subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Program Files\\Checkpoint\\Endpoint Connect\\trac.exe connect -u username -p password"])
elif 'd' or 'D' in sys.argv[1]:
  subprocess.Popen(("C:\\Program Files\\Checkpoint\\Endpoint Connect\\trac.exe disconnect "))
```

Comment: Check the whole word, like
`if sys.argv[1].lower() == "connect"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you run it second time, sys.argv[1] = 'disconnect', so there's letter 'c' inside. you'd better use:

```
if sys.argv[1].lower().startswith('c')
```

or

```
if sys.argv[1].lower().startswith('d')
```

Comment: Perfect thanks very much, that has sorted it, now to build it up to add my other parts.

Answer (score 1):

if ('c' or 'C') in sys.argv[1] should be ok. Priority issue, i guess.
You have to split Popen command arguments to separate array members, btw.